# OpenMapTiles server and Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mapbox-gl-js, openmaptiles

I have an OpenMapTiles Server already running and serving vector tiles that are used in a Leaflet based application, together with mapbox-gl.

Layer with the vector map is added to the leaflet map with code like:

*mbgl = L.mapboxGL({
        attribution: '\xA9 OpenMapTiles [\xA9 OpenStreetMap](http://osm.org/copyright) contributors',
        accessToken: 'xxxxx',
        style: 'url-of-style'
        }).addTo(map);*

However, this requires that the device and browser allows WebGL and that is causing trouble because there are still many users with systems not compatible with WebGL.

Is there some way to overcome this drawback?  For instance, is it possible for OpenMapTiles server to serve raster maps and use them somehow with Leaflet directly or with the help of mapbox-gl?  I have already tried this in several ways but without success, so I wonder if it is even possible.

Any ideas will be welcome.

Comment: What do you think about `tileserver-gl` and the server-side rendefing? http://tileserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints.html#rendered-tiles

Comment: If you don't get a response here you could try [gis.se]

Comment: https://openmaptiles.org/docs/host/tileserver-gl/